# Compute the number of permutations of given set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I have a question regarding permutation:
Compute the number of permutations of the set
$\{r, s, t, u\}$. Which of the following is the correct answer?

1. $n^r = 4^4 = 4\times4\times4\times4 = 256$
   or:
2. $n! = 4! = 4\times 3\times 2\times 1 = 24$
   Where $n$ is the number of elements of the given set.

Comment: Permutations with and without repretitions.

Comment: Why not try a smaller example first?  For the given set $\{r,s\}$ are there $2^2=4$ permutations or $2!=2$?

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 4! = 24.

Let us see why:
The easiest, most intuitive way to look at this question, is to see it as "in how many ways can we organize four elements in four positions?".

If we look at the first "place", we can have four options.

Once we have set a value from the set to be our first, there are 3 left to place in the second position.

We can do this in 3 ways.
So, overall, we need to multiply them - because for every choice we made at the first step (four possible) there are 3 possible choices now.

In the second position we now can place only two elements, which are the two left in the set. We can choose in 2 ways. So, here we need to multiply our overall count by 2 - because for every option that we have counted so far, there are two now that can be made.

In the last position we can place only one element, which we can do in one way.

So, we have counted 4x3x2x1 = 24 ways!

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: you're welcome!